# Mongoose creating additional document to store default values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

When a user creates a note, the Mongoose API creates a document with values for the note by the user and then creates an additional document with default parameters only. Is there a way to get rid of it from the database?

My schema for Note is like this:

```
var NoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    text: String,
    color: {
        type: String,
        default: "white", <--- default
    }
    favorited: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,   <--- default
    }
});
```

In `mongo` console:

```
// Document it creates and what I expect
{ 
    "_id": "58795af461e2db2db804997d", 
    "title" : "Testing: Hello", 
    "favorited" : false, 
    "color": "strawberry", 
    "author": { 
        "id": "587950df61e2db2db8049972", 
        "username" : "tester" 
    } 
}
// Additional default (unneccessary) document created:  
{ 
    "_id": "58795af461e2db2db804997e", 
    "favorited": false, <--- from the Schema
    "color": "gray" <--- from the Schema
}
```

It doesn't do anything from the user's point of view, but I don't want it to create an additional document with default values for every single note. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your schema to set `required` and `minlength` validation for `title` and `text` fields.

```
var NoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 15   // <--- Set the minimum title length
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 100   // <--- Set the minimum text length
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
        default: "white",
    }
    favorited: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
});
```

This will ensure that if `title` and/or `text` are missing then the document will not be saved. Also if their length is less than their `minlength` values, the document will not be saved.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't solve the problem. Even when I do that, it still creates an additional default document that I don't want to be stored in the database. Here's the document it creates: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("58795af461e2db2db804997e"), "favorited" : false, "color" : "gray", "__v" : 0 }`

Comment: @NarulaKeshav How are you saving the document?

Comment: I create a `noteData` object with note data using `body-parser` package from Express. Then I add this object to User's `note` array by doing User.findById(....) and inside I do `Note.create(noteData, function(err, ..)`

Comment: Okay, in that case you must call [Document#validate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate) function on the Note document in your code. It will check for the validation rules mentioned in the schema above. If there is no validation error then you should proceed to save it.

Comment: Tried that too, but still the same problem. I'm not sure why that would be creating that additional document if the fields like `title` and `text` are `required` ...

Comment: So you are saying that there was no validation error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133125/discussion-between-narulakeshav-and-santanu-biswas).